# How to know in advance the number of records for each reducer in hadoop map reduce \ Ignore partitions based on size

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a job that splits data into groups. and I need to keep only the large partitions (above a certain threshold).

Is there a method to this?

one solution is to iterate over all the items and store them in memory, and flush them only if they reach a certain size.
However, this solution may require a very large amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a general straightforward solution (apart from storing until the size is reached). Maybe if you provide more details this will give us more inspiration?

Comment: I thought there might be some relevant class that can be overriden through the Job Configuration (like set Partitioner, Comperator, etc.) - but I didn't find something that appears relevant.

Comment: The problem is that you only have a key, if the information is not in the key then the partitioner is helpless I think. You can always move information inside your keys but it cannot be deterministic, you could make guesses, when a value occurs less than a threshold in a map, then don't emit it? Problem is that you need to keep everything in memory then, which could also be problematic. Another idea could be to run a number of sample jobs (where you process random maps) and estimate the relevant keys from the samples, that way you could only emit those keys which are likely to be relevant?